# How to change Jetty icon

Tags: icons, jetty

everyone.

I am using jetty. and I find it shows its logo "j:" on browser's tab. just like tomcat will show a little cat.

And I know how to change tomcat's logo with my own. I can replace favicon.ico under ${tomcat}/webapps/ROOT.

Now I want change jetty's logo with my own. Can tell me how to do it? I didn't find any image under ${jetty}

and I do not want use this way:

Because I must write one line code in every html page. I think it is not very good way.

Answer (score 1):

For Jetty 9  - you will need to edit jetty.xml which is located $Jetty_Home/etc

1. Change this line

   ```
   `<New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />`
   ```

   To

   ```
   `<New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"> <Set name="serveIcon">false</Set> </New>`
   ```
2. Stop Jetty
3. Start Jetty
4. Remember to clear your browser history & cached inc. images and files

Cheers

Comment: I think this will just make any favicon to not appear. Still don't know how to change it with your own

Comment: Thank you @cm3579, currently, it displays favico and not a jetty server ico.

Answer (score 1):

In the older 10.5.3.0 version of Jetty that I'm using (not by choice!) the favicon.ico is stored within a JAR file.  I do not know whether this behavior persists in the latest releases of Jetty.

The JAR file containing the favicon.ico file is jetty/lib/jetty-6.1.21.jar.

I copied that to a temporary directory & unzipped it.  The favicon.ico was in the ./org/mortbay/jetty/ subdirectory.  I replaced that file with my own favicon.ico, re-zipped the file, and replaced the original .jar file with my own modified version *after* I created a backup of the original file.

The modified file seems to be displaying the new favicon.  Whether this is supported by the Jetty folks is anyone's guess, but it might be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the favicon by adding below statement to your HTML

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />`

You can provide absolute or relative path to your favicon.